# How to run selenium(Java) tests of wikia app - https://github.com/Wikia/selenium-tests

Tags: selenium, mediawiki

I have downloaded this - https://github.com/Wikia/selenium-tests.
But unable to run tests as I couldn't find the selenium-config repository.
The following instructions are given in readme.file of repository-
.......... 
Running Tests 
The following steps should get you set up for running Selenium tests locally on your machine:

1. Clone this repository to your local machine (not your dev box).
2. Clone selenium-config repository to your local machine.
3. Copy
   `config_default.yml` file and name it `config.yml` (this will be
   your    local config).
4. Modify credentialsPath property in `config.yml`
   to point    to credentials.xml file from

cloned selenium-config repository 
..... 
can anybody guide me how to find selenium-config repository?

Answer (score 1):

`selenium-config` is a private repository. However, it is not mentioned in the README.

Reference to this can be found inside the `build.gradle`

`Can't download configuration without user and password \n (config is a private repository)`

https://github.com/Wikia/selenium-tests/blob/master/build.gradle#L78